# Variance calculation warning: longer object length is not a multiple

Tags: warnings, variance, gam, gratia

I'm getting this warning after checking the variance components of my model. I don't have NA's and the warning goes away when I remove this `s(CYR.std, fSite, bs = "fs")` term. Is it possibly related to having only 1 observation associated with a `fSite` in a year (`CYR.std`)? I get the same warning with the full dataset.

```
gratia::variance_comp(m1)
# A tibble: 4 × 5
  component         variance   std_dev   lower_ci    upper_ci
  <chr>                <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>
1 s(sal)            4.47e-10 0.0000211 0.00000968   0.0000462
2 s(CYR.std,fSite)1 3.92e- 2 0.198     0.112        0.352    
3 s(CYR.std,fSite)2 6.13e- 1 0.783     0          Inf        
4 s(CYR.std,fSite)3 3.43e- 7 0.000586  0.000268     0.00128  

Warning messages:
1: In lsd - crit * sd.lsd :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In lsd + crit * sd.lsd :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Random subset of data recreates the error:

```
MyVar <- c("fCYR", "CYR.std", "fSeason", "fSite", "area_sampled", "num", "sal")

x <- shrimp2[MyVar][sample(nrow(shrimp2[MyVar]), 100), ]

na_count <-sapply(x, function(y) sum(length(which(is.na(y)))))

na_count <- data.frame(na_count)
na_count
             na_count
fCYR                0
CYR.std             0
fSeason             0
fSite               0
area_sampled        0
num                 0
sal                 0

library(mgcv)    

m1 <- bam(num ~ s(sal) + 
            
            CYR.std*fSeason +
            
            s(CYR.std, fSite, bs = "fs"), 
          offset(log(area_sampled)),
          method = "fREML",
          discrete = TRUE,
          family = nb(link = "log"),
          data = x)
```

**UPDATE:**

I even get the same error with the most basic of random effects...

```
m <- bam(num ~ s(sal) + 

            CYR.std + 
           
            fSeason +
         
            s(fSite, bs = "re") + 

            s(fCYR, bs = "re"), 
          offset(log(area_sampled)), 
          method = "fREML",
          discrete = TRUE,
          family = nb(link = "log"),
          data = x)

> mgcv::gam.vcomp(m)

Standard deviations and 0.95 confidence intervals:

            std.dev     lower      upper
s(sal)   0.01623266 0.0105176 0.02505317
s(fSite) 0.83502554 0.3549272 1.96453684
s(fCYR)  0.54846495 0.3553660 0.84649014

Rank: 2/2
Warning messages:
1: In lsd - crit * sd.lsd :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In lsd + crit * sd.lsd :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Full dataset (n=1327):

```
> table(shrimp2$CYR.std, shrimp2$fSite)
    
     1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41
  0  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  1  2  2  2  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
  1  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
  2  2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  1  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
  3  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
  4  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
  5  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  1  2  2  2
  6  2 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  1  1
  7  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
  8  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
  9  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  1  2  2  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  1  2  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
  10 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
  11 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
  12 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
  13 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
  14 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
    
     42 43 44 45 46 47
  0   2  2  2  1  2  2
  1   2  2  2  2  2  2
  2   2  1  1  1  1  1
  3   2  2  2  2  2  2
  4   2  2  2  2  2  2
  5   2  2  2  2  2  2
  6   1  1  1  1  1  1
  7   2  2  2  2  2  2
  8   2  2  2  2  2  2
  9   2  2  2  2  2  2
  10  2  2  2  2  2  2
  11  2  2  2  2  2  2
  12  2  2  2  2  2  2
  13  1  1  1  1  1  1
  14  2  2  2  2  2  2
```

Smaller dataset:

```
> dput(x)
structure(list(fCYR = structure(c(9L, 9L, 12L, 15L, 11L, 11L, 
8L, 11L, 2L, 9L, 1L, 14L, 13L, 10L, 3L, 15L, 14L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 
9L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 15L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 9L, 5L, 
5L, 2L, 6L, 11L, 6L, 13L, 12L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 12L, 
1L, 14L, 14L, 5L, 8L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 15L, 3L, 8L, 12L, 12L, 15L, 
4L, 11L, 5L, 1L, 9L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 15L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 11L, 14L, 3L, 
10L, 11L, 13L, 7L, 4L, 11L, 3L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 1L, 10L, 10L, 1L, 
10L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 15L, 11L, 14L), levels = c("2008", "2009", "2010", 
"2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", 
"2019", "2020", "2021", "2022"), class = "factor"), CYR.std = c(8L, 
8L, 11L, 14L, 10L, 10L, 7L, 10L, 1L, 8L, 0L, 13L, 12L, 9L, 2L, 
14L, 13L, 5L, 6L, 0L, 8L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 14L, 
10L, 0L, 1L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 10L, 5L, 12L, 11L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 4L, 0L, 11L, 0L, 13L, 13L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 14L, 2L, 
7L, 11L, 11L, 14L, 3L, 10L, 4L, 0L, 8L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 14L, 6L, 
2L, 5L, 10L, 13L, 2L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 6L, 3L, 10L, 2L, 9L, 9L, 
8L, 0L, 9L, 9L, 0L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 14L, 10L, 13L), fSeason = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("DRY", "WET"), class = "factor"), fSite = structure(c(18L, 
33L, 27L, 15L, 47L, 8L, 3L, 29L, 34L, 6L, 44L, 8L, 11L, 14L, 
4L, 43L, 19L, 39L, 15L, 47L, 24L, 36L, 19L, 39L, 39L, 33L, 16L, 
35L, 40L, 11L, 42L, 31L, 40L, 25L, 6L, 35L, 38L, 16L, 34L, 42L, 
47L, 9L, 27L, 11L, 29L, 35L, 36L, 46L, 11L, 21L, 1L, 31L, 10L, 
32L, 6L, 22L, 42L, 25L, 44L, 28L, 15L, 20L, 8L, 14L, 23L, 6L, 
8L, 32L, 2L, 45L, 31L, 20L, 7L, 37L, 46L, 39L, 36L, 35L, 4L, 
1L, 19L, 16L, 2L, 4L, 23L, 20L, 10L, 27L, 15L, 34L, 40L, 8L, 
13L, 26L, 39L, 43L, 34L, 39L, 22L, 46L), levels = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", 
"15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", 
"26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", 
"37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47"
), class = "factor"), area_sampled = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), num = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 19L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
3L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
6L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 2L, 2L, 1L), sal = c(4.78, 18.55, 19.72, 25.08, 16.48, 15.47, 
24.88, 15.12, 25.69, 23.64, 33.58, 24.37, 31.77, 28.98, 21.14, 
25.37, 20, 23.03, 27.01, 27.46, 8.06, 29.7, 27.44, 30.41, 21.13, 
22.47, 16.8, 23.54, 37.1, 30.16, 29.26, 22.08, 31.68, 10.56, 
19.1, 14.73, 29.34, 17.77, 20.07, 32.71, 30.47, 27.76, 11.26, 
31.8, 26.85, 10.79, 17.31, 26.85, 20.62, 26.58, 30.46, 23.9, 
23.01, 22.3, 20.49, 18.19, 29.74, 21.27, 23.74, 25.42, 23.46, 
26.33, 30.99, 29.99, 29.77, 21, 29, 21.37, 15.83, 32.36, 33.52, 
24.76, 28.48, 17.23, 33.79, 19.89, 2.79, 21.75, 29.98, 15.18, 
13.48, 29.94, 27.39, 37.13, 4.04, 21.7, 11.29, 6.3, 11.37, 21.44, 
19.82, 10.03, 22.73, 21.73, 8.76, 13.49, 18.21, 35.25, 4.15, 
25.88)), row.names = c(268512L, 258208L, 329600L, 387560L, 312120L, 
309912L, 253424L, 298136L, 109720L, 264096L, 75128L, 381304L, 
341008L, 290224L, 128304L, 383880L, 373760L, 198776L, 235208L, 
65376L, 258576L, 238336L, 203192L, 245328L, 89664L, 142104L, 
134560L, 202088L, 227112L, 393080L, 296112L, 65744L, 110824L, 
258760L, 195280L, 187736L, 110456L, 211656L, 299056L, 199328L, 
337144L, 335120L, 266304L, 204664L, 200984L, 210552L, 220488L, 
172096L, 83040L, 323528L, 62800L, 375968L, 379280L, 173200L, 
254160L, 107512L, 152592L, 68872L, 384064L, 132720L, 252136L, 
323344L, 317456L, 395840L, 164552L, 309360L, 177248L, 65928L, 
271456L, 199880L, 162344L, 231344L, 386088L, 220672L, 138792L, 
207792L, 310096L, 376704L, 122048L, 275320L, 299976L, 342296L, 
225272L, 166024L, 315248L, 120392L, 275504L, 282864L, 267960L, 
66296L, 286544L, 276608L, 83408L, 288200L, 256736L, 264832L, 
220120L, 402096L, 315064L, 378912L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need to speak to Simon Wood about this one; the warning is raised in his `mgcv::gam.vcomp()`, which gratia calls (all `variance_comp()` does is put some sugar on top of the hard work mgcv does; returns the output as a tibble, adds the variance as a column).

I think there is something weird going on. The warnings come from these [two lines](https://github.com/cran/mgcv/blob/aff4560d187dfd7d98c7bd367f5a0076faf129b7/R/mgcv.r#L4347-L4348) in gam.vcomp:

```r
ll <- lsd - crit * sd.lsd
ul <- lsd + crit * sd.lsd
```

and the problem comes from the `sd.lsd` vector. This isn't of length 4:

```r
> lsd
           s(sal) s(CYR.std,fSite)1 s(CYR.std,fSite)2 s(CYR.std,fSite)3 
       -3.4839424        -2.8555567        -0.4410871        -1.3827881
> sd.lsd
[1] 2.5010946 0.3471288 1.1410316
```

and this is because the hessian from the outer iteration is not of the same rank when fitted with `bam()` as it is with `gam()`, and I think the current code either assumes something that is `gam()`-specific or fitting with `bam()` is highlight a potential issue with your data/model. For example, fitting with `discrete = FALSE` (on the subset you provided) resulted in a warning that something didn't converge (even though the outer iteration seemingly converged).

In this model, fitted with `gam()`, the hessian (of the smoothing parameters) is a 5x5 matrix because the outer iteration is also over $\theta$ parameter for the negative binomial. The code in `gam.vcomp()` checks to see if there are any extra parameters outwith the smoothing parameters being estimated and if there are it drops those columns from the hessian. In the case of the `bam()` fit, the hessian is actually a 4x4 matrix - which seems odd - even though there should be a $\theta$ being estimated.

I think that there's a column missing with `bam()` is actually telling you something about the model; it looks like it is over-fitted to the data. If I look at `gam.vcomp()` on the model fitted with `gam()` I see:

```r
> gam.vcomp(m1) 

Standard deviations and 0.95 confidence intervals:

                       std.dev         lower         upper
s(sal)            0.0102080074  2.083020e-06  5.002517e+01
s(CYR.std,fSite)1 0.0008840011  1.561116e-82  5.005766e+75
s(CYR.std,fSite)2 0.6726926834  3.229118e-01  1.401359e+00
s(CYR.std,fSite)3 0.0008083213 1.717862e-201 3.803468e+194

Rank: 4/4
```

where at least two of the parameters have effectively 0 variance and a confidence interval that goes from (effectively) 0 to (again effectively) infinity, which is a pretty strong indication that you are asking too much from this model and data combination.

The smooths estimated by `s(CYR.std,fSite)` are linear when fitted with `gam()`:

[image]

while with `bam()` with `discrete` set to `TRUE` we see

[image]

and with `discrete = FALSE` we see

[image]

but I doubt I'd believe the two latter fits, especially in light of the model with `discrete = FALSE` emitting a convergence failure warning, and the problems highlighted with `gam.vcomp()` on the `gam()` version.

While I think this is ultimately a data issue — you're asking too much from a these data — there is a problem with `gam.vcomp()` as it is dropping a column from the hessian for the theta but the hessian is 1 rank lower than it should be. And I think it should be 5x5 because there is $\theta$, 1 smoothing parameter for `s(sal)` and three for `s(CYR.std, fSite, bs = "fs")`. But I'm not familiar enough with `bam()` to know why it is returning a smaller hessian than `gam()`. Unless it is the result of the rank-deficiency of the model given the data causing some problem earlier in the chain — `bam()` does a lot of fancy matrix operations so something could be getting lost in one of those operations that don't happen when fitting with `gam()`.

When you contact Simon, feel free to link to this Q&A, but do send him the subset of data as a CSV file and the complete code needed to load the data and fit the model, raise the warning. You want a minimal working example:

```
# load mgcv
library("mgcv")
# load data either via a read.csv() call or your `structure()`
# !!!! Note I have truncated it here for this example
x <- structure(list(fCYR = structure(c(9L, 9L, 12L, 15L, 11L, 11L, 
8L, 11L, 2L, 9L, 1L, 14L, 13L, 10L, 3L, 15L, 14L, 6L, 7L, 1L,
....
66296L, 286544L, 276608L, 83408L, 288200L, 256736L, 264832L, 
220120L, 402096L, 315064L, 378912L), class = "data.frame")

# fit model
m_bam <- bam(num ~ s(sal) + CYR.std*fSeason + s(CYR.std, fSite, bs = "fs"), 
          offset(log(area_sampled)),
          method = "fREML",
          discrete = TRUE,
          family = nb(link = "log"),
          data = x)

# variance comps, raises warning
gam.vcomp(m_bam)

# but with `gam()` everything OK
m_gam <- bam(num ~ s(sal) + CYR.std*fSeason + s(CYR.std, fSite, bs = "fs"), 
          offset(log(area_sampled)),
          method = "REML",
          family = nb(link = "log"),
          data = x)
gam.vcomp(m_gam)

# note different-sized hessians
# bam()
m_bam$outer.info$hess
# gam()
m_gam$outer.info$hess
```

Show the pertinent output in your message (that from `gam.vcomp()` and the hessians, plus the `bam()` call) but make sure Simon and just run the code himself (so don't interleve output).

I will admit to getting very confused about your modelling process with all your questions. It seems like non of your questions fit the same model structure, yet are seemingly being fitted to the same data. I'm a little worried you are torturing these data to the point of death and their death throws are higlighting issues. Do you really need FS smooths in the full data?

Comment: Will do, thank you! Every model structure I tried was proposed to me by other people (that don't know each other), but I suppose I gained more insight as I tried different things. This might be why it all seems very random (I'm open to suggestions!). Here is what I have now: gam(num ~ ...fSeason + s(CYR.std, by=fSeason, k=12) + s(fSite, bs = "re") + s(fSite, by = fSeason, bs="re"). No warnings or crazy C.I.'s, any thoughts? I also tried s(CYR.std, fSite, bs="re"), but the variance was basically zero. Can you elaborate on the concept of testing the data to death?